# HDIV Use Case: Integration with Third Party Site posting to HDIV secured site

Tags: spring, jsp, security, hdiv

I wanted to know in a specific use case like below will the HDIV protection work for a spring mvc application and if yes how -

Use Case 1 - Third party website posting to HDIV protected site (without login autentication);flow is like this
-  Third Party site -> form post -> HDIV Secured Page -> Validate parameters -> Forward to another HDIV Secured Page for business processes
 - How to configure the start URL in this case?

Use Case 2 - Third Party website wants to access a page on the website secured with HDIV through an iframe

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, you only have to put as `Start Page` the first request. There is no problems with iframes.

I hope it helps.